# why are there two different results?

Tags: java

[image]
Why are there two different answers for `("bc" + 2 + 3)`? and `(2 + 3 + "bc")` I only change the order of `"bc"` and `3` and `2` but the system gives totally different answers for the addition

Thanks in advance

Comment: Because order of evaluation

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], e.g. working code example and sample output.

Comment: please edit your question and copy/paste both code and output instead of a screenshot. indexing will be made much easier.

Answer (score 3):

`+` works both as arithmetic as well as concatenation operator. And all the expressions are executed from left to right. So in case of `2 + 3 + "bc"` it first adds 2 and 3 acting as arithmetic operator and then when it find string on one side and number on other at that time it acts as concatenation operator.

Answer (score 0):

When whatever thing is added to a string using `+`, Java treats it as if you want to concatenate that thing to the string.

Let's look at each case.

```
"bc" + 2 + 3
```

`+` is left associative, meaning that the 2 leftmost operands are evaluated first. In this case it is `"bc" + 2`. This evaluates to `"bc2"`. Then we evaluate `"bc2" + 3`, producing `"bc23"`.

```
2 + 3 + "bc"
```

The two leftmost operands are evaluated first: `2 + 3` evaluates to 5. This is because there is no string in the expression. `+` performs a mathematical addition. Then we evaluate `5 + "bc"`, producing `"5bc"`.

Answer (score 0):

Java is reading your operations from left to right. If the first variable is a string the rest of the values will be concatenated to it. In your second case, you have to numbers first, which are summed up and that value is then concatenated with following string. This will en up with results: first case: "bc23" and the second case "23bc".

Answer (score 0):

In your case if you place string value in the first Java will treat all the values as string unless the first two values are calculable.
here is the example code which will help you to understand the basic concept.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
     System.out.println("bc"+2+3); //bc23
     System.out.println("bc"+(2+3)); //bc5
      System.out.println(2+3+"bc");  //5bc
      System.out.println(2+3+"bc"+2+3); //5bc23
      System.out.println("bc"+2+3==2+3+"bc");// false  

    }
```

[image]